# How to operate on encrypted files in a locally restricted sandbox (restricting local machine from access to outputs/intermediates)?

Tags: encryption, local, sandbox

I need to operate on encrypted files in a local sandbox. This means I want to limit local access to the key and unencrypted file. I want a script to ping a webserver to securely pull the key in a JS environment, use this key to unencrypt files, operate on them, and send information to the webserver without the local user having access to any outputs or intermediates. Is it possible to locally sandbox in a submitted script so that it runs locally but what it is operating on is completely unaccessible to the local machine after submission? (only accepts inputs - outputs, intermediates in memory unaccessible)

Answer (score 0):

No, that is similar to performing a DRM scheme without controlling the runtime environment. Maybe you can lock other scripts out (hard enough) but certainly not the userthat controls the browser. Best you can do is obfuscating the values...

Comment: could you think of anyway to decrypt encrypted files in a browser without a user having access to the decrypted files?

Comment: Yes, a some kind of closed environment. If the user cannot take control of the browser you can protect the encrypt files. Otherwise you are always open to attack. You cannot really create a closed environment in something as open as a browser. You can use a sandbox to keep things from breaking out, not from something breaking in.

Comment: or what about using processing power to operate scripts on a VMware client like setup - so you use your processing power to operate on files protected in the VM

Comment: You can think up as many schemes as you like, but browse on DRM on this site (and e.g. security.stackexchange.com and try and understand why DRM is doomed, as long as it runs on something controlled by somebody else.

Comment: datz I think humanity has more urgent problems myself, but don't let that deter you :)

Comment: I can guarantee at least a mil for anyone who can solve this.

Comment: owl, humanity needs this - I can't go into details, but trust me.

Comment: We need to build a "new kind of sandbox"

Comment: Not really, you need to vote up and accept instead of going on chatting.

Comment: OK, never mind, I've flagged this conversation, hoping that it will be deleted. In my opinion, by now the question should meet a similar fate.